# Login dialog comes for windows authentication in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

i have applied windows authentication for asp.net project and it is working. when i try to access any secure page then first time login dialog comes....but why. when i already login to windows before running project then why should i again give my windows credential to access asp.net web project any secure pages.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**so guide me how to suppress the login dialog pop up**. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your browser to automatically log you in. Your site probably needs to be in the local intranet zone. Windows Integrated Authentication is built into Internet Explorer. Some other bowsers may not support it.

Comment: can u tell me how to configure my browser to automatically login. r u talking about IE browser or other browser. beside IE other browser support windows authentication.

Comment: In Internet Explorer - go Tools,  Internet Options. On the Security Tab, select Trusted Sites. 
Then click Sites. Type in the URL ('http://yourserver' or 'http://*.yourdomain') and click Add - you may need to un-check the require server verification checkbox.
Click close.
Click the Custom level... button. Scroll down to the end and select the 'Automatically logon with current user name and password' option.
Click OK. Click OK again.
Shut down all your browser windows and try access your site again.

Comment: but what will occur if i test the site from other browser. the same login dialog come for other browser. so guide me if i can suppress login dialog for other browser.

Comment: For Firefox, you may need to configure it. See here: https://docs.gosecureauth.com/display/docs/How+to+enable+Integrated+Windows+Authentication+(IWA)+in+Mozilla+Firefox
Opera 9.01 and later versions can use NTLM/Negotiate, but will use Basic or Digest authentication if that is offered by the server.
Google Chrome works as of 8.0.
Safari works may work - if you are using Kerberos (Negotiate).

Comment: i would like to use Digest authentication not basic.

Comment: You need to use NTLM/Negotiate for windows authentication.